How are TVS diodes for ESD protection meant to be used on low voltage data lines?
Most TVS diodes seem to have a breakdown voltage higher than 5V and a clamping voltage even higher than this. This TVS diode meant for USB applications from TI has a breakdown voltage of 6.7V and higher clamping voltages.
How is this sufficient to protect a 5V USB input? The voltage at the IC will likely be higher than the maximum rating.

Right, putting them directly in parallel sees both devices share some current, as both clamping mechanisms are activated.
Which one draws more current, depends on the internal resistance of both.  Consider the equivalent circuit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

But ICs are rarely if ever specified in terms of ESD characteristics (current, voltage and duration), so determining the balance of currents is generally not possible.  The TVS current curve could be safely above the IC's, or the IC takes the brunt of it; who knows.
We can force the situation with a simple addition: series resistance.

simulate this circuit

This isn't always tolerable: most USB devices nowadays have internal termination resistors, or support High Speed or above which doesn't require them; and the added resistance can reduce signal bandwidth, or drive strength of outputs (particularly for strong drivers like logic bus and RS-485), or introduce error where minimal error is desired (e.g. analog outputs -- there is still a solution however: use a buffer op-amp and take feedback from after the resistor, so that clamp diodes and TVS protect the op-amp in this two-stage manner).
BTW, notice that USB interfaces are supplied by 3.3V.  If the device only uses 5V externally, there will be a 3.3V regulator internal to it -- and most likely a bypass capacitor required thereon, though it might also be completely self-contained.  It is reasonable to assume some combination of clamping diodes to this 3.3V supply, as well as zener or snapback diodes to ground, are used to protect the interface pins.
Low (or no) series resistance can still be tolerable, as one can make some hand-waving assumptions about the IC's internal resistance, and figure that, while the TVS might not reduce the IC's burden all the way to zero, it might still be comparable to, say, a 2kV ESD strike, versus the 8kV being applied.  This greatly reduces or eliminates (if so rated) damage to the device, though it doesn't eliminate possible acute failure modes like CMOS latchup (we're well beyond the typ. 100mA limit of that behavior), for which a power cycle is likely necessary to clear the fault; or excessive power dissipation destroys the circuit instead (a good reason to use local current limiting in sub-circuits, rather than one massive power supply for everything all together).
To get below the latchup threshold, we need to tolerate enough series resistance to do so, and perhaps use two external TVS or clamp diodes in the process.  We can then guarantee freedom from latchup -- a category A or B performance criteria (see IEC 61000-6-1 §4).  As you can see, this is not always possible in general, and some compromise between robustness and performance is necessary.
There are also alternative solutions to ESD, mechanical for example.  Notice the USB connector is designed with pins deeply recessed within a shield housing.  Pins cannot be struck directly by the ESD test probe, or any ISO equivalent finger.  The shield will be targeted instead.  As long as shield integrity is maintained (and it often is not; often, on vocal advice from online platforms such as this, no less!), those ESD currents can wash over the circuit, along the shield, safely away from signal lines.  Devices then only need to handle reduced levels (induced ESD, leakage through poor quality shields or flaky connectors, and charged-cable events), extending the performance envelope.

A further comment on ESD and shielding, since it is relevant here and likely to extend prior conversations with readers: one cannot assume shielded connectors, cables, devices, etc. are perfectly immune to ESD.  I recently performed some ESD testing on my office desk here, and the HDMI monitor (a well known brand name) glitched out (go black for a second then resume normal operation) with almost every strike.  I don't know whether this is due to HDMI signaling, DDC corruption, or internal (power cable related?) effects, but suffice it to say it's not performance criterion 'A' at least.

It is sufficient because 6.7 volts is tolerated. The USB port can tolerate 6.7 volts and higher voltages. TVS diodes are not intended to eliminate the surge but to make it survivable by limiting the voltage. You would not want a TVS diode with a much lower voltage rating because normal data could cause false trips. You need headroom.

How do you know how much your input can tolerate after using clamp or TVS diodes? That doesnt seem to be well specified for most parts.

They shunt away the majority of the pulse's energy so that the remainder can be dealt with by the ESD suppression diodes built into the protected device.

I thought that relying on internal ESD diodes was a bad practice. Is there some unspoken rule that the overvoltage on a input after using a TVS diode wont damage the device? How is that determined?

@JamesScholl Any chip will have the ESD limits listed in the data sheet. The chips have internal ESD protection just to survive casual handling and being in the pick and place machine, which is not a very rough environment. You put an extra ESD protection for external interfaces like USB if you want to handle more ESD. Not relying on internal protection diodes usually means to not abuse them for clamping say 5V signal with series resistor on a 3.3V powered MCU.

TVS diodes protect low-voltage data lines like USB by clamping short-duration transients (e.g., ESD spikes) to safe levels. While their breakdown voltage (e.g., 6.7V) and clamping voltage are above 5V, they are still effective because:
Fast Response Time: TVS diodes react in picoseconds, faster than IC damage mechanisms.
Transient Tolerance: ICs can tolerate short overvoltage spikes during ESD events.
Proper Selection: Choose a TVS diode with:
Reverse standoff voltage > 5V.
Breakdown voltage just above 5V.
Low capacitance for high-speed lines.
For USB, TVS diodes like TI’s ESD122 or similar are ideal.
